# Periodicity of the solution of a non-linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, periodic-functions

Consider the following non-linear differential equation,
$$
\dot{x}(t)=a-b\sin(x(t)), \ \ x(0)=x_0\in\mathbb{R},
$$
and assume that $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers with $a>b$.
Note that the solution $x(t)$ exists and can be analytically computed ([see here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dx(t)%2Fdt%20%3D%20a-b*sin(x(t)))).

> **My question:** Is $\cos(x(t))$ a zero-mean periodic function of $t\ge 0$?

Further on, in case the answer to my previous question is in the affirmative, it should be that
$$
\left|\int_{0}^t \cos(x(t))\, \mathrm{d}t\right|\le K(a,b), \ \ \forall t\ge 0,
$$
where $K(a,b)$ is a positive constant depending on $a$ and $b$ only. So an additional question is: Can we find an explicit expression for $K(a,b)$?

---

**N.B.** Numerical simulations seem to confirm the above claims. However I couldn't quite prove them. So any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change of variable $x(s)=u$ yields $$du=x'(s)\,ds=(a-b\sin u)\,ds$$ hence, for every $t$, $$\int_0^t\cos x(s)\,ds=\int_{x_0}^{x(t)}\frac{\cos u\,du}{a-b\sin u}=\frac1b\log\left(\frac{a-b\sin x_0}{a-b\sin x(t)}\right)$$ Thus the integral is indeed $0$ when $x(t)=x_0+2k\pi$ for some integer $k$, and it is extremal when $x_0=-\frac\pi2+k\pi$ and $x(t)=\frac\pi2+k\pi$ for some integer $k$ (maximal if $k$ is even and minimal if $k$ is odd), then its absolute value is

> $$K(a,b)=\frac1b\log\left(\frac{a+b}{a-b}\right)$$

As a way of (very) partial confirmation of this formula, note that, by an elementary change of variable, $$K(a,b)=\frac1bK\left(\frac ab,1\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for your neat answer! From your integral expression can we also conclude that $\cos(x(t))$ has zero mean?

Comment: Yes, please read the sentence starting by "Thus".

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but my understanding is that the fact that the integral is zero over a period depends on the behavior of $x(t)$. So I don't see how to conclude that the integral is periodically zero w.r.t. $t$

Comment: If $x(t)=x_0+2\pi$ then $$\int_0^t\cos x(s)\,ds=\int_{x_0}^{x(t)}\frac{\cos u\,du}{a-b\sin u}=\ldots ?$$

Comment: What I do not see is whether there *exists* a $t$ such that $x(t)=x_0+2\pi$

Comment: Because $t\mapsto x(t)$ is increasing with derivative at least $a-b>0$ everywhere.

Comment: I was re-reading your answer and I'm still a bit confused. It is not clear to me how the fact that $t\mapsto x(t)$ is increasing should imply that $\cos(x(t))$ is periodic. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

As in my response to your question [Behavior of a non-linear differential equation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296923/behavior-of-a-non-linear-differential-equation) on MO, consider the ODE on the one-dimensional torus (that is, circle) $\mathbb{T} = \mathbb{R}/2 \pi \mathbb{Z}$.  By (ergodic theoretical version of) Liouville's theorem (see, e.g., Theorem 1 on p. 48 of [Ergodic Theory](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9781461569299) by Cornfeld, Fomin and Sinai) the probability measure
$$
d\mu = \frac{\sqrt{a^2 - b^2}}{2 \pi} \frac{1}{a - b \sin{x}}\, d\lambda,
$$
where $\lambda$ is one-dimensional Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{T}$, is an invariant (probability) measure for the flow $\Phi$ generated by the ODE on $\mathbb{T}$.  Further, the flow $\Phi$, being a reparametrization of the flow generated on $\mathbb{T}$ by $\dot{x} \equiv 1$, is uniquely ergodic.

By the (continuous time version of) Birkhoff ergodic theorem for uniquely ergodic DSs (see, e.g., [Uniform convergence of Birkhoff averages and unique ergodicity](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/152132/uniform-convergence-of-birkhoff-averages-and-unique-ergodicity) on MO), for every continuous function $f \colon \mathbb{T} \to \mathbb{C}$ its time averages
$$
\frac{1}{t} \int\limits_{0}^{t} f(\Phi(s, x_0))\, ds
$$
converge, as $t \to \infty$, uniformly in $x_0 \in  \mathbb{T}$, to its space average
$$
\int\limits_{\mathbb{T}} f(x) \, d\mu(x).
$$
In our case we have
$$
\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} \frac{1}{t} \int\limits_{0}^{t} f(\Phi(s, x_0))\, ds = \frac{1}{T} \int\limits_{0}^{T} \Phi(s,x_0) \, ds,
$$
where $T = 2\pi/\sqrt{a^2 - b^2}$ is the period.

Taking $f(x) = \cos{x}$ we have
$$
\int\limits_{\mathbb{T}} f(x) \, d\mu(x) = \frac{\sqrt{a^2 - b^2}}{2 \pi} \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\cos{x}}{a - b \sin{x}} dx = 0.
$$

This is a (hopefully correct) answer to your first question.  Regarding the additional question, one can take just one solution (for instance, corresponding to $x_0 = 0$), so there is $K = K(a, b)$, but I do not know how easily one can find an explicit expression.